# radio button ignores required attribute

Tags: html

I am coding a form [click here](http://www.kjds.org/templates/articlecco_cdo/aid/2871032/jewish/Untitled.htm). On top of the form I have three radio buttons that are set `required-"required` (tried just required, required="true"), but the radio buttons are ignoring this attribute. So I can submit the form without selecting any radio button. I googled and found that I am doing it the right way. I can have one required attribute in the family of radios and it will still work, but it does not for some reason.

```
<ul class="regForm">
                        <li style="width:100%">
                        <div><input type="radio" tabindex="1" value="Guests" name="Reservation" onChange="att(1)" id="guests" required="required" />                                                <span class="record">Guest(s) $150 per guest</span></div>
                        </li>
                        <li style="width:100%">
                        <div><input type="radio" tabindex="1" value="Table" name="Reservation" onChange="att(2)" id="table"  required="required"/>                                              <span class="record">Table(s) $1,500 per table <span class="note">(seats 10)</span></span></div>
                        </li>
                        <li style="width:100%">
                        <div><input type="radio" tabindex="1" value="Unable to Attend" name="Reservation" onChange="att(3)" required="required"/>                                               <span class="record">Unable to Attend</span></div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
```

Please help me to fix it.
Thank you

Comment: Code in your question please.

Comment: @j08691 this is html, there is a link, but yes posted a snipplet

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I see you have a "Co_Tools" is undefined javascript error. That might be causing the other validation to not work.. Not sure. On a side note, I would code my own javascript validation for the form, instead of relying on HTML 5. This is a public website, and surely you will end up with a user that doesn't have an HTML 5 compliant browser.  In addition, this is area of HTML 5 that intrudes too much into functionality (which should be handled by script) over presentation.

Comment: @j08691 fair point, poseted the code

Comment: @DavidP as far as i know i can only check this with javascript on forms submission, this way i have to code submit button? unfortunately due to this cms limitations i have no access to submit button. it works for the fields, like the First Name field throws a required message. it looks like only radios having a problem

Comment: Can you replace the submit button with just a button? If so, you can validate the form yourself using javascript function for its onclick event. If it passes, you can then do a document.forms[0].submit(). If not, you can present a dialog with missing form values.

Comment: @DavidP thanx David unfortunately cant do that with them, i think i gonna go drive crazy their support

Answer (score 1):

You only need one "requiered". For example like this:

```
<form>
<label for="input1">1:</label><input type="radio" name="test" id="input1" required value="1" /><br />
<label for="input2">2:</label><input type="radio" name="test" id="input2" value="2" /><br />
<label for="input3">3:</label><input type="radio" name="test" id="input3" value="3" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2du3s/1/)

You should change your code to this

```
<input type="radio" tabindex="1" value="Guests" name="Reservation" onChange="att(1)" id="guests" required />
```

Comment: no, it still does not work...if you update the link you can see that it still does not take affect, sorry i wish it was that easy